# To change one's potential (abilities) to actual

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I was wondering if the structure of the sentences below sounds natural:

- > 1- You can do everything. Just you have to **change your potential to actual.**
- > 2- You can do everything. Just you have to **change your potential abilities to actual.**

Please kindly let me know which one sounds idiomatic and natural to you? If none of them, then please let me know how shall I express these meanings?

Comment: This construction is awkward and would be better if rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't sound natural to me. I think you could go with "to realize one's full potential", which is defined as:

> to become the best one can be

by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reach%2Frealize%20one%27s%20full%20potential).

You could say:

> You can do everything. You just have to realize your full potential.

Or maybe more shortly:

> You just have to realize your potential.

[The relevant meaning of realize](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/realize) is:

> Achieve (something desired or anticipated); fulfil.